# Does US Consular verify if one's relative is in US if it's not indicated in the ds-160?

Tags: visas

I am married, and I want to apply for f1 visa to the US. Unfortunately, my parents have overstayed their visa. I am worried that if I indicate this on my visa application, I may be denied visa to US so I don't want to indicate this information on my ds-160.

I want to know if supposing I don't indicate this information on my application form it will be verified.

Answer (score 4):

You might possibly be refused a visa to the US if your parents are there and have overstayed. Then again, you also might have a very strong application regardless, and still be approved. The question for the visa officer is *whether you intend to immigrate to the US* or not. Where your parents live and their immigration status is only part of that question.

If you are found to have engaged in deception on your visa application, you will get [a *lifetime* ban from the US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/93444/3221). Obviously this is not a good idea, unless you plan to never visit the US in your entire life (and want to waste $160 USD). You should assume that the visa officer can verify the immigration status of your parents, and act accordingly.

Comment: You should add that an omission of this sort would definatey be seen as wilful and probably material. Material means that this omission is the difference between approval and refusal. The OP would be at a bigger risk of a ban should his visa be approved and later his misrepresentation discovered. If they have this information at the time of the interview, chances of a ban are greatly diminished.